# How to render templates from two different directories/folders?

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I have a `home_pages` directory. And I also have a `affiliate_pages` directory.

 How can I render templates from both their directories?

(p.s. i know this is very vague, but do not have access to my code as I am using a different computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by including the directory in the path you pass to `render_template()`:

```py
@app.route('/')
def home_page():
  return render_template('home_pages/index.html')

@app.route('/affiliates/<aff>')
def affiliate_page(aff):  
  return render_template(f'affiliate_pages/{aff}/index.html')
```

That way, you don't have to show `home_pages` in the URL path.

(make sure your directories are in the main directory you set, the default is `templates` and you can read more about changing the default template directory [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.render_template).)